# Proper Handling of PropertyReferenceException for Query Params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

In a Spring (Boot) application we're heavily using the `Pageable` interface and have our controller methods mostly defined like so:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Thing>> fetchAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Page things = this.thingService.findAll(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(things.getContent(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When accessing it via the following endpoint:

`/api/things/?size=5&page=1&sort=name,asc`

If the sort property, `name` in this case, is misspelled or doesn't exist, a `PropertyReferenceException` is thrown and a 500 sent back to the user with a message such as:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-01-30 13:40:47",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException",
  "message": "No property name found for type Thing!",
  "path": "/api/things"
}
```

While this is technically the right error message, it doesn't seem like 500 is the appropriate code to respond with. 5xx level message are typically reserved for server issues and this is technically a user issue so more like a 4xx level message.

Best I can see if that maybe it's just a 400. My question is a) is 400 an appropriate response in this situation and b) is there an elegant way to handle this. My current solution is to catch that Exception in my `ControllerAdvice` class and just return the 400.

Comment: Depends on where are you getting the error. If the error is thrown inside of any class then Spring will treat it as 500 (and you have to converted to 400) but if the error is thrown by Spring before reaching your controller method I think Spring shoud throw 400.

Comment: Okay, thanks. For now, I'm catching it in my `@ControllerAdvice` class and returning a 400 from there. Good enough for now. Just curious what other options there were.